Managing object lifecycles in OpenAI api
Which OpenAI api objects are cleaned up by the server vs. which are the app's responsibility? I'm most interested in:
Assistants, VectorStores, VectorStoreFiles -- all seem intuitively like things that will be retained until the app removes them explicitly.
Threads -- seem like they would be retained also, but there's no list endpoint. Must I make a record elsewhere of threads I've created so they can be deleted later?
Messages -- maybe these are these subordinate to threads and have the same (unknown) lifecycle?
by contrast, Runs and RunSteps -- seem intuitively transitory, that I shouldn't depend on being list-able or retrieve-able later, nor should I expect to need to delete explicitly.
But these are just guesses. Can someone give me better guidance?

In an experiment, I created several threads and retained their ids (remember that there's no list endpoint for threads as of this writing). I queried these threads subsequent runs and discovered that they were findable  within about 30 days.
Around 40 days later, get access to thread produces a 404 not found error. This is pretty good evidence that threads are automatically deleted after 30 days. I haven't run a similar experiment with Runs/Run Steps.
